# How to list contents of a local .rpm file using dnf?

Tags: rpm, dnf

On a machine which (possibly) doesn't have access to internet I have a local rpm file. I would like to inspect it's contents, that is what files will be installed once I install it. Is it possible to do so with just `dnf`? With other tools?

Edit: the system **does not have yum**, only dnf. While I probably could add rpm for development purposes I can not assume it will always be available.

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest `rpm` for this task:

`rpm -qpl ./some_package.rpm`

Comment: I specifically asked about dnf because as of now the system does not have rpm.

Comment: `dnf` is a front-end for rpm. You can not handle .rpm files without `rpm`

Comment: Urgh, my bad, I'm tired and confused rpm with yum

Comment: Which is also a front-end for rpm

Answer (score 7):

You only need `rpm`; you can list the files shipped in an RPM with:

```
rpm -qlp /path/to/your.rpm
```

An additional `-v` will add file details:

```
rpm -qvlp /path/to/your.rpm
```

To see the included scripts, which may also create files:

```
rpm -qp --scripts /path/to/your.rpm
```

Comment: I specifically asked about dnf because as of now the system does not have rpm.

Comment: `dnf` needs `rpm`, are you sure your system doesn’t have it?

Comment: my bad, I'm tired and confused yum and rpm...